# Регулярные выражения пропускают не учтённые символы

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Не могу разобраться в регулярном выражении. Есть код :

```
if (!preg_match("/[0-9-\s()+]{3,}/", $number)){
        return false;
    }
    return $number;
```

Очевидно, что проверят правильность ввода телефонного номера: разрешено цифры, пробелы, скобки, плюс не менее 3 символов. Это работает, если изначально ввести буквы, возвращается ложь(как и должно быть), но если я вожу, например: +3(8011)123-**ав**-24, или если после цифр ввести **что-угодно**, возвращается истина. Знаю что тут просто должно быть, но что делаю не так?

Comment: Нужно указать начало и конец строки `^regex$`. Но что-то немного странная у вас регулярка на телефон (контрпример - `+380---3430--343+` и серавно сработает)

Comment: А как избежать повторных символов?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"/^[0-9-\s()+]{3,}$/"
```

Решение моего вопроса.